# Audio Interface wiring diagram of Yaesu FT-65 TNC cable

Tags: yaesu, audio, tnc, wiring

I want to imitate this cable, but I don't know-how. Yaesu FT-65 TNC cable. Is it need to series a resistor inside of those?

[image: Yaesu FT-65 TNC cable]

Comment: Hi Jerome, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!